# Calculate median of column X based on conditional/group column Y values found in a list

Tags: r

I would like to modify this line:

```
`with(EquityFundamentals, median(EquityFundamentals$Forward.P.E[EquityFundamentals$Industry == "Entertainment"], na.rm = "TRUE"))`
```

- to use a list of names, not just "Entertainment"
- The list of names is characters in a vector called "Sectors"
- The output would be:

  - new values for every sector (e.g. a median for every sector; MedianEnergy, MedianTech, etc.) OR
  - a data frame with the Sector in column 1 and Median in column 2

Data:

```
> EquityFundamentals
  Sector.Title. Forward_P.E.Title.
1        Energy                6.7
2        Energy                7.5
3          Tech               10.4
4          Tech               11.5

structure(list(
  Sector.Title. = structure(c(1L,1L,2L,2L),
    .Label = c("Energy","Tech"), class = "factor"),
  Forward_P.E.Title. = c(6.7,7.5,10.4,11.5)),
  .Names = c("Sector.Title.", "Forward_P.E.Title."
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of your data? Makes it easier to answer.

Comment: Hi - I did a basic edit to show how it's laid out. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Are you able to use dput() on your data (or a small subsection of it), then paste that into your question?

Comment: Does a screenshot help? https://i.imgur.com/x7LdzXZ.png

Comment: Hi, screenshots tend not to be to helpful, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for how to make a good example.

Comment: You probably want something like `aggregate(Forward.P.E ~ Industry, EquityFundamentals, median)` - there are many similar questions on this site.  Perhaps take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/calculate-the-mean-by-group).

Comment: H 1 you nailed it. Elegant and the way I was hoping it would work. I knew it was an easy task for a guru. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the mean by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/calculate-the-mean-by-group)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (not the most elegant way, but works).

```
Sectors <- c("Entertainment", "Energy", "Tech")
for (i in 1:length(Sectors)){with(EquityFundamentals, print(paste((Sectors[i]), median(EquityFundamentals$Forward.P.E[EquityFundamentals$Industry==(Sectors[i])], na.rm = "TRUE"), sep=",")) )}
```

There are many ways to do the task, including `by`, `dplyr`, `split` and several others, which are comprehensively described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/calculate-the-mean-by-group) post.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this one a shot, too. H 1 gave a great version that worked also.